# Highcharts x-axis label not corresponding with value in tooltip

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[image]

I'm formatting the chart with this

```
, labels: {
formatter: function () {
    return Highcharts.dateFormat('%a %d %b', this.value);
               }
  }
```

I'm adding my values in an array like this:

```
series.push(new Array(new Date(dates).getTime(), value));
```

Also in my controller i'm adding this:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
        global: {
            useUTC: false
        }
    });
```

For some reason my dates are correct in the tooltip but are one day off in the label, any suggestions where to look?

Comment: Chart is rounding to the closest first of the month. I usually solve this by setting my time stamps to be the first of the month in question (rather than the last day of the month), for monthly data like this. Could also use `tickPositions` to set the axis tick values explicitly without changing your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I eventually did to correct the problem was to add this function to the javascript controller:

```
function formatDate(date) {
        var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

        return months[date.getUTCMonth()] + ' ' + date.getUTCDate() + ', ' + date.getUTCFullYear();
    }
```

And using it in the highchart configuration with:

```
labels: { formatter: function () {
                return formatDate(new Date(this.value));
                                 }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @jlbriggs wrote, you can create an array with x values of all points and return it in `tickPositioner` function.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositioner

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/jtfc5wk0/